# Get an object name

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

The question was solved by T.S.

---

I try to get a name of object and I couldn't find the right commmand.
For example:
I have PicturetBoxes wich call "picX*Something*". So I use for loop for checking if the character of the name of the object in the 4th place equal to "X" (if so - unvisible the object).
I tried this, but it wasn't work:

```
For Each control In Me.Controls
        If TypeOf control Is PictureBox Then
            If control.Name(3) = "X" Then
                DirectCast(control, PictureBox).Visible = False
            End If
        End If
Next
```

How can I get an object name?

Comment: If X is in uppercase your check will find nothing. And by the way, you talk about TextBoxes but search for PictureBoxes

Comment: String is array of Char. Try this: `control.Name(3) = Char.Parse("x")`. And, you don't need to do `DirectCast(control, PictureBox).Visible = False` because `Visible` is property of `Control`. Do `control.Visible = False`

Answer (score 0):

If you are searching for controls of type PictureBox whose name in the fourth char position contains the letter "X" in uppercase you could write

```
' Using IEnumerable methods to isolate only the controls of type picturebox required
For Each pictBox In Me.Controls.OfType(Of PictureBox)().Where(Function(x) x.Name(3) = "X"c)
    pictBox.Visible = false
Next
```

Keep in mind that this will work only on the controls that are contained in the Form Controls container. If your form has more containers (GroupBoxes, Panels) and the picture box is contained inside these controls then you need to loop over the GroupBox or Panel controls collection. This scenario needs a recursive function to examine every container

```
Public sub HidePics(cc as Control.ControlCollection)    
    For Each controlObject In cc
        Dim ctr = DirectCast(controlObject, Control)
        HidePics(ctr.Controls)
    Next
    For Each pictBox In cc.OfType(Of PictureBox)().
                        Where(Function(x) x.Name(3) = "X"c)
        pictBox.Visible = false
    Next
End Sub
```

Call it from form code as

```
HidePics(Me.Controls)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Note that `Me.Controls` only lists the controls that are placed
   dirctly on the form. Controls placed on other controls like
   TabControls, GroupBoxes, SplitContainers will not be listed. You
   will have to recurse on these controls if your picture box is on
   another control.
2. `control.Name(3)` returns a character. so use a character literal
   `"X"c`
3. String comparison is case sensitive by default, therefore you will
   not find the `"X"` in `"picXSomething"` if you are searching for
   `"x"`.
4. You don't have to cast the picture box, since all controls have a
   `Visible` property.